# Default I18n scope in controller with Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm using [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) and I have a controller in directory `app/controllers/api/v1/sessions.rb`

I am currently using the following command to display messages:

```
I18n.t('anything', scope: 'api.sessions')
```

But there is a redundancy, because throughout the file is used the same scope. How can I make it standard? To be able to use something like:

```
I18n.t('anything')
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just write a method?

```
private

def translate_for(key)
  I18n.t(key, scope: 'api.sessions')
end
```